# Drainage line do not match DEM stream line using Arc Hydro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arc-hydro, stream

[image]

I've been running my DEM using Arc Hydro, drainage line output do not match the DEM or the basemap stream.

What could be the problem?

The red line is my stream from delineated DEM, the blue line is the basemap from ArcGIS software.

Below are my process:

1. DEM repositioning
2. fill sink
3. flow direction
4. flow accumulation
5. Stream Def

etc based on Arc Hydro sequence.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. With so little information provided, the set of possible issues is staggering. If you provide the list of things you *have* done, it might be possible to recommend something else.

Comment: More details please on "do not match the DEM or the basemap stream." Screen shots of the difference would be good.